# $\frac{a^3+1}{a}+\frac{b^3+1}{b}+\frac{c^3+1}{c} \ge 2\sqrt{(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c})\cdot (\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a})}$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c$ is positive number, $abc=1$ Prove that:$$\frac{a^3+1}{a}+\frac{b^3+1}{b}+\frac{c^3+1}{c} \ge 2\sqrt{(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c})\cdot (\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a})}$$
My attempt:
$$P=\alpha \cdot (\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}) + \frac{(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a})}{\alpha} \ge 2\sqrt{(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c})\cdot (\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a})}$$
I need find $\alpha$ to P has same level with $\frac{a^3+1}{a}+\frac{b^3+1}{b}+\frac{c^3+1}{c}$ but i cant. Can any body help me ?

Comment: related https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1078435p4724559

Comment: Isn't it $\dfrac{a^3+1}{a^2}+\dfrac{b^3+1}{b^2}+\dfrac{c^3+1}{c^2}$??